# Deploying file from NuGet package that copies to consuming application's output directory automatically

Tags: .net, package, nuget, .net-standard

I am trying to create a .NET Standard 2.0 NuGet package that standardizes how I consume NLog across .NET Framework and .NET Core applications. I have an nlog.config file that is the standard boilerplate layout for all the apps I will be writing. I also have a couple of classes that basically wrap NLog, and standardize how I interact with the library.

I want my NuGet package to deploy this standard nlog.config xml file to the project consuming my package, and set the `Copy To Output Directory` value to either `Copy Always` or `Preserve Newest`. I know it has something to do with the .nuspec file, and build folders, and .props/.targets files, but I am completely lost now after trying numerous posts like these:

[Set content files to "copy local : always" in a nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package)

[How to add files to build folder in csproj NuGet package without .nuspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077052/how-to-add-files-to-build-folder-in-csproj-nuget-package-without-nuspec)

[Setting file properties with NuGet using .targets file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788961/setting-file-properties-with-nuget-using-targets-file)

I don't know who to believe. It seems there are several ways to go about it, but none of them have worked. Is it an issue with .NET Standard? Am I just doing something wrong?

My .csproj file sections of interest:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="build">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="nlog.config" Pack="true" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```